# implementing a checkers game in rust

Tags: rust

```rust
impl Coordinate {
    pub fn jump_targets_from(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Coordinate> {
        let mut jumps = Vec::new();
        let Coordinate(x, y) = *self;
        if y >= 2 {
            jumps.push(Coordinate(x + 2, y - 2));
        }
        jumps.push(Coordinate(x + 2, y + 2));
        if x >= 2 && y >= 2 {
            jumps.push(Coordinate(x - 2, y - 2));
        }
        if x >= 2 {
            jumps.push(Coordinate(x - 2, y + 2));
        }
        jumps.into_iter()
    }

    pub fn move_targets_from(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Coordinate> {
        let mut moves = Vec::new();
        let Coordinate(x, y) = *self;
        if x >= 1 {
            moves.push(Coordinate(x - 1, y + 1));
        }
        moves.push(Coordinate(x + 1, y + 1));
        if y >= 1 {
            moves.push(Coordinate(x + 1, y - 1));
        }
        if x >= 1 && y >= 1 {
            moves.push(Coordinate(x - 1, y - 1));
        }
        moves.into_iter()
    }
}
```

I am following the "Programming WebAssembly with Rust" book by kevin hoffman and i cant understand what these 2 function do, its written they are used to calculate all possible jumps and moves from a particular coordinate but i cant understand how its happening

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you about this code?

Comment: the logic like how does that function calculate all the possible jumps @mkrieger1

Comment: Do you mean that you do not understand the rules of the checkers game?

Comment: i know the rules but i dont get how that function calculates all jump like how does adding and subtracting 2's from the coordinates calculates all the jumps

Comment: What do you think the 4 spaces 2 up/down & 2 left/right are if not all the possible spaces reachable by a jump? It's not *valid* jumps, just spaces reachable by a jump.

Answer (score -2):

1. jump_targets_from(&self)

This method calculates the possible jump targets from the current coordinate. It creates an empty vector called jumps to store the calculated targets. The method then destructures the Coordinate object into x and y variables.

The first condition if y >= 2 checks if the y coordinate is greater than or equal to 2. If it is, it adds a new Coordinate object to the jumps vector by incrementing the x coordinate by 2 and decrementing the y coordinate by 2.

The next line unconditionally adds another Coordinate object to jumps by incrementing the x coordinate by 2 and incrementing the y coordinate by 2.

The following condition if x >= 2 && y >= 2 checks if both the x and y coordinates are greater than or equal to 2. If true, it adds a new Coordinate object to jumps by decrementing the x coordinate by 2 and decrementing the y coordinate by 2.

Finally, if the above conditions are not met, it adds another Coordinate object to jumps by decrementing the x coordinate by 2 and incrementing the y coordinate by 2.

After populating the jumps vector with all possible jump targets, the method converts it into an iterator using into_iter() and returns it.

2. move_targets_from(&self)

This method calculates the possible move targets from the current coordinate. It follows a similar approach to the jump_targets_from method.

It creates an empty vector called moves to store the calculated targets. The method then destructures the Coordinate object into x and y variables.

The first condition if x >= 1 checks if the x coordinate is greater than or equal to 1. If it is, it adds a new Coordinate object to the moves vector by decrementing the x coordinate by 1 and incrementing the y coordinate by 1.

The next line unconditionally adds another Coordinate object to moves by incrementing the x coordinate by 1 and incrementing the y coordinate by 1.

The following condition if y >= 1 checks if the y coordinate is greater than or equal to 1. If true, it adds a new Coordinate object to moves by incrementing the x coordinate by 1 and decrementing the y coordinate by 1.

Finally, if the above conditions are not met, it adds another Coordinate object to moves by decrementing the x coordinate by 1 and decrementing the y coordinate by 1.

After populating the moves vector with all possible move targets, the method converts it into an iterator using into_iter() and returns it.

Comment: i undersrand what that function does but i dont understand the logic

Comment: I believe if you want an answer from Andrew you can just go and ask ChatGPT directly.

Comment: ok i added more details

Comment: @AndrewArrow i understand what each if block does i dont understand how that function calculates all possible jumps. you understand?